# Is there a way to time the execution of each iteration of a loop in a stored procedure

Tags: mariadb

I have a stored procedure that is taking a long time to execute.  This particular stored procedure calls another stored procedure inside a loop.  I know if I run the stored procedure inside the loop on a specific record its not taking much time (just have not found the offending records).  Is there a way to keep track of the amount of time it takes to execute each iteration of loop?  I would like to store this info off in a table along with id of the record I am working with in that particular iteration in an attempt to identify which records are causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To measure execution time, just use the timestamp() and now() functions:

```
# Set start time
SET @stime:= NOW();
# Execute stored procedure
CALL myproc(@id,@params);
# calculate execution time in seconds
SET @exectime:= timestamp(NOW()) - timestamp(@stime);
# save execution time
INSRT INTO mytable (id, execution_time, procedure) VALUES (@id, @exectime, "myproc");
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for thanks! I did modify one thing:  `SET @exectime:= TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, @stime, NOW());`

Comment: Use `NOW(6)` to get more precision.